# Changing style properties

Tags: javascript, css

I have an element, where the following style applies:

```
<style>
    #hover  {
      border: 1px green;
      position: absolute;
      left: -100px; /* Should not be seen initially */
    }
</style>
```

In my code, I am reading and modifying the 'left' property. I ended up with the following solution, which does work:

Reading the property:

```
hover=document.getElementById("hover");
left=window.getComputedStyle(hover,null).getPropertyValue("left");
```

Changing the property:

```
hover.style.left="25px";
```

I found this seeming asymmetry rather puzzling. For example, the following does not work:

Reading the property - **does not work that way, always returns empty string**

```
left=hover.style.left
```

Changing the property - **gives error 'modifications not allowed in this object'**

```
computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(hover,null);
computedStyle.setProperty("left",'-101px','important');
```

I'm aware that my last attempt is even incomplete; after creating a new style object, I need somhow to put it back to the element, but the error message already occurs when I call setProperty.

Now my question: Is it true, that the only way to get and set a style property, is as I did it initially, or is there another possibility where I can achieve the same goal? In particular, I wonder why I can not **read** a style with the expression 'hover.style.left', but only set it.

Comment: Are you fine in using jQuery?

Comment: I'm using a bit of jQuery, but I still don't know much about it yet. Would you mind showing me as an example, how my code would look like with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.style.*` map on to styles applied **directly** to the element. There are two ways to do this:

- Through the DOM
- Through the HTML `style` *attribute*

You can read from it, but it will only read the CSS properties directly applied to the element. Since your properties are initially set through the style sheet, they don't appear here.

---

`getComputedStyle` computers the style for an element in the same way that the browser does when it tries to render it. It applies rules from style sheets and those directly applied to the element, applies the cascade logic and so on.

You can't write to it because the rules come from lots of different places.

---

Hence, if you want to get rules from either inline or elsewhere you have to use `getComputedStyle`, but whatever you write has to be through `.style.*`.